# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError... How can I use C++ files in my Android App in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I have some .cpp and .h files and I created a *libs* folder and put them there. Then I added in my *local.properties*

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\PATH...\\Android\\android-ndk-r10e
```

and finally I added in my *build.gradle* the following

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```

That's it. I can't run my app and I always get the same error. I've read something about *.so* files and *armeabi* folders, but I don't know what is that. Have you solved this problem before? there is something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's done XD, all that I needed to do is compile the C++ files with the NDK in the terminal using the ndk-build command. It created my .so files in the armeabi folders automatically